# Error al generar apk con Proguard

Tags: android, android-studio, mapsforge

Estoy desarrollando una app de geolocalizacion. Necesito ofuscar el codigo de mi aplicacion, cuando activo proguard y genero el apk me muestra lo siguiente:

Warning: com.caverock.androidsvg.SVGImageView: can't find referenced class com.caverock.androidsvg.R$styleable
Warning: com.caverock.androidsvg.SVGImageView: can't find referenced class com.caverock.androidsvg.R$styleable
Warning: com.caverock.androidsvg.SVGImageView: can't find referenced class com.caverock.androidsvg.R
Warning: org.mapsforge.map.rendertheme.rule.RenderThemeHandler: can't find referenced class org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser
Warning: org.mapsforge.map.rendertheme.rule.RenderThemeHandler: can't find referenced class org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.

He encontrado todo tipo de soluciones en internet y aun no puedo resolver este problema. Si alguien pudiera ayudarme.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Está diciéndote que la clase com.caverock.androidsvg.SVGImageView está referenciando a com.caverock.androidsvg.R. y es probable que no exista.

Solo debes añadir estas lineas a tu proguard-rules:

```
-dontwarn com.caverock.androidsvg.SVGImageView
-keep class com.caverock.androidsvg.SVGImageView
```

Y lo mismo si hay algún otro error similar.

Answer (score 0):

Puntualmente es por el proguard ubicado en el build.gradle; optimiza el código ofuscándolo. Acorta los nombres de funciones , clases ,objetos por seguridad y aveces salen errores de este tipo.

```
  buildTypes {
    release {
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Debes colocar en sus reglas que mantenga la clase tal cual y no la ofusque, en la ruta .txt que tengas en tu gradle 'proguard-android.txt' o 'proguard-android-optimize.txt' colocas estas lineas.

```
-dontwarn com.caverock.androidsvg.SVGImageView
-keep class com.caverock.androidsvg.SVGImageView
```

recomendación: prueba siempre tus APPs en release con el proguard.
Este tipo de errores son comunes. A mi me salió en producción un 404 - not found porque no reconocía una api , espero haberte ayudado !